# Install Python Packages to specified desitination(away from default or root)

Tags: python, pip, pypi, site-packages

Regarding installing Python Packages (PyPi), I am trying to define the individual library location(away from default or root). In other words, figure out how to specify the user library location. Right now when I install packages, it's default to home (or root), but it needs to be relocated to /data004. So, I am trying to get it off the root file system.

This is the code i use at the command line to install packages:

- python -m pip install  - - user SomeProject  -f  ./  - -no-index

[image: Sample Code]

Any ideas or tricks to work through this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip has an --install-option= feature

```
PREFIX_PATH=/home/dkennetz/local_install/

python -m pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" PyDF2
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the -f -no-index so it doesn't go to the internet?

Comment: yeah you can pass the -f and --no-index

Comment: python -m pip install --install -option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" PyDF2 -f ./ --no-index

Comment: Would that be the correct format? Because it gives me an error when running it on command line

Comment: yeah so I just ran: `pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" TEToolkit -f /path/to/TEToolkit --no-index` and it installed locally -f needs to be the link path to the site-package setup.py loc

Comment: Wait could you chat real quick?

Comment: sure i can do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185499/discussion-between-james-davinport-and-d-kennetz).